# opening multiple files

Tags: python

I would like to open multiple files with the file names changed little.

For example , I want to open

```
abc.001.xyz.010.trj
```

After some operation onto the data file I want to save the results into file:

```
out.abc.001.xyz.010.trj.dat
```

And this process should go on until 10 files.

I know how to open this file

```
readfile = abc.001.xyz.010.trj
f = open(readfile, "r")
```

later I tried to write into file

```
outfile = out.readfile
f = open(outfile, "w")
```

but I fail. Expect to get output file as

```
 out.abc.001.xyz.010.trj.dat
```

for every loop.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't there be quotes arround the file names? Also what is `out.readfile`? What is `out` there?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: I assume he meant `'out.'+readfile`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know how to open this file

*No, you don't.* Your initialization for the `filename` is invalid and would result in `SyntaxError`.

You should have written

```
readfile = "abc.001.xyz.010.trj"
f = open(readfile, "r")
```

And in similar way, to open the output file

```
outfile = "out."  + readfile
f = open(outfile, "w")
```

Btw, there are other issues, in your code which is not very conventional.

Generally People Tend to `open` files and `close` it and don't rely on garbage collections, and even better, enclose the entire file operation inside a [with](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) construct

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Thanks for highlighting the error too. I missed out the quote. This code helped me to simplify my calculation now. Tough I am new to python but still keep learning. Regards